# node js, socket.io, redis and pm2

Tags: node.js, rest, redis, socket.io, pm2

Our system includes a NodeJs Restful API server. This server also serves as a socket IO server. Many devices will connect to the server by socket io, the user can control the device by calling restful API, the server will transfer command to the device through the socket IO. We used pm2 to cluster the API server. Can you help how to use Redis.io server to support to send a message from a cluster to a specific socket instance?

Answer (score 3):

If you already have a redis server setup, all you have to do is setup the socket.io-redis adapter: https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-redis

From there, it's best to have the incoming socket.io connections join a device specific room. This is typically achieved with a `socket.join()` from the `connection` event.

From there, you can call your `.to().emit()` method to send the data to the device. Using rooms allows you to ignore the socket and transmit the message to the device no matter which instance they are connected to